# Spring Data: How to maintain cache consistency in transactional methods?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, caching, data-consistency

Let's assume we have a standard Spring Boot application with JPA. We have repositories, services and REST controllers. On the service layer, we have this:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User getUserById(userId: String) {
        return this.userRepo.findById(userId).orElse(null);
    }    

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public User saveUser(User user){
        this.userRepo.save(user);
    }
}
```

We want to cache the result of `getUserById`, either via `@Cacheable` or via an explicit cache. We have the following two options:

- If a call to `saveUser(...)` occurs, we call `repo.save(user)` and then we **immediately** put the saved user into our cache (write-through).
- If a call to `saveUser(...)` occurs, we **invalidate** the corresponding entry in the cache. Once the user is requested by ID again, we read it from the database and put it into the cache.

Both methods have issues:

- If we write-through, we risk that the database transaction fails at some point **after** the `repo.save(user)` call and is rolled back. We may have written a version of the user into our cache that never hit the database. Our cache is out-of-sync with the database.
- If we only invalidate the cache, there is a time period between the invalidation and the transaction commit where a concurrent transaction may call `getUserById(...)`. This transaction will still read the old version of the user and write it into the cache. The result is that we have outdated data in our cache.

Is the built-in spring cache susceptible to these issues as well? How do you avoid such problems in your application?

Comment: Don't use Springs cache abstraction for that... Instead configure the 2nd level cache of your JPA provider which already does all of that. don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Your caching strategy has other issues. Unless you are dealing with flat objects, these will all have references, which themselves can be stale. You may get multiple very different instances built for some user referenced object tying up memory just because it has multiple paths in the object graph that made it into your cache. Do it carefully! As for invalidation and when to cache - EclipseLink (Hibernate will have something similar I'm sure) has cache coordination you can leverage to have your cache listen for the changes. Native (session?) events also can fire after transaction commit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got confused here. There is the Spring Boot side of caching, which is supposed to cache **method results**, and then there is the 2nd level cache of the JPA provider. These are different things with different purposes. My bad for mixing them up.